# Get HTML tags interpreted in field output

Tags: views, theming

I have an event calendar view and I would like to be able to have HTML inside the field interpreted instead of printed as text i.e. on http://quaaoutlodge.com/myspecial-myevents , the Easter Brunch on April 20th has following event description:

Easter Brunch 
`<strong>`** Reservations required ** `</strong>` - call 250.679.3090 but instead it shows up as: Easter Brunch 
`< strong>` ** Reservations required ** `< /strong>` - call 250.679.3090 - why is this and how can get the HTML to be parsed before display?

Comment: What do you mean by *"HTML to be parsed before display"*? HTML tags are display thing, they get parsed at the display stage only. Probably your problem is with < encoded as `&lt;`, right? So what you want is for them not to be affected - if anything you want to *avoid* parsing?..

Comment: @Molot My table cell loos like this: `<td class="views-field views-field-field-table-description" >
            Easter Brunch <br />
&lt;strong&gt;** Reservations required **&lt;/strong&gt;  - call 250.679.3090          </td>`

Comment: @Molot But how can I get this done? I only have `Strip HTML tags` in my rewrite settings and that's not what I want to do either.

Comment: There is an issue in views about that. I work around it decoding entities in field's tpl file, if I have to.

Comment: @Molot In the field's tpl file? How and where do I find my fields tpls at all?

Comment: View's settings, right column, on the bottom.

Comment: you add a CSS class to style the field output you mean? But this is not what I want, I'm looking to format only parts of a field differently, you know.